# How to show MYSQL errors in AJAX?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am learning AJAX with PHP-MYSQL.
I have three files index.php, process.php and database.php...
Javascript is included inside the index.php.

**index.php**

```
<main>
    <header>
        Displaying MYSQL errors
    </header>
    <!-- Display error -->
    <section id="error"></section>
    <div id="submit_div">
        <button id="submit" name="submit_btn">Submit</button>
    </div>
</main>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    let submit_btn = document.getElementById('submit');
    let error = document.getElementById('error');

    function showHint() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "process.php", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-with', 'XMLHttpRequest');

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                var simple_text = xhr.responseText;
                error.innerText = simple_text; //print the error.
            } // if
        } // onreadystatechange()

        // Sending the request
        xhr.send();
    } //showHint()

    submit_btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        showHint();
    }, false);

</script>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php

    require_once('database.php');

    $db = db_connect();

?>
```

**database.php**

```
<?php
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "abhishek");
define("DB_PASS", "wrongpassword"); // I set the wrong password to print the error.
define("DB_NAME", "ajax");

function db_connect(){
    $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    confrim_db_connect();
    return $connection;
}

function confrim_db_connect(){
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        $msg = "Database connection failed: ";
        $msg .= mysqli_connect_error();
        $msg .= " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")";
        exit($msg);
    }
}
?>
```

So now on clicking the button, ajax request starts and send the request to process.php page which return the response in `xhr.responseText`.  
**Please note that**, In `database.php`, I gave the wrong password for database to get the error as response.
So when I pressed the button to get the content of xhr.responseText.
It gave the content of `xhr.responseText` (this is what I want) -

> **Warning**: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'abhishek'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in **/var/www/html/AJAX/sql_ajax/database.php** on line **5**
>   Database connection failed: Access denied for user 'abhishek'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (1045)

I have no problem yet.
But If I parse the result in `JSON` using
`var in_json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);`
then it is giving me error -

> VM949:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
>   at JSON.parse () at show_json ((index):79) at
>   XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange ((index):58)

So The problem is that json is unable to parse the result.
So now My question is -
**How to parse the above result in json ?**
I already know that how to print the error in `jquery`.
**Help here with javascript...**

### PLEASE READ MY QUESTION AGAIN, I added more information...

Comment: `xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200` this means "if the HTTP response code is 200" (and so it's everything fine), do what is inside that block.. after you have to write `else if(xhr.status == 500) do somethig...` and the do something is the code which you will use to show the error, because if there are errors in the PHP script, will be returned a 500 HTTP response

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia thanks, I think you are close to my answer but please read my question again because I have added more info in it.

Comment: why you have to parse the error with json? it's just plain text, so you just need to assign the simple_text to the error.innerHTML (if the request states 500 )

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia According to your answer, there is no error in PHP script, I just gave the wrong password to coonect to database and  print that error through AJAX.

Comment: well so you just need to TRY and CATCH any error during parsing `try {
        let json = JSON.parse(response);
    } catch(e) {
        alert(e); // error in the above string (in this case, yes)!
    }`

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia You are going wrong here, because I am able to print the `xhr.responseText` inside `xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200`   in process.php which means request is successfull. I wanted to parse it with JSON beacuse i can extend my code with json.dbError to print the error else json.noError to alert some success message.

Comment: that code is JS code, not PHP...

Comment: What's the purpose here really? Are you aspiring to have query errors for all requests? Keeping debug info enabled on production? Optimizing for edge cases? Else, why not be content with looking at the JS/net console for development?

Comment: I asked this question because jquery is printing what I want here, but i want to get it in JS.

Comment: The server is returning HTML because `json_encode()` is not being used, and possibly `display_errors` is enabled in php.ini. If you want to return an error condition, you shouldn't be using 200 response but rather 400/500 response. And if you want to return JSON, you have set proper headers to do that. @AlbertoSinigaglia working around broken responses is not so great an alternative to fixing the server to send valid responses.

Comment: As `$db = db_connect();` in process.php get called then `exit($msg);` get executed  in databse.php and it stops the execution there and didn't come back to `process.php`. So I don't know where to use the jsone_encode. _Can you help me_

Answer (score 0):

According to the discussion in comment section with @AlbertoSinigaglia, I am posting the solution.
So the `xhr.onreadystatechange()` function looks like -

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        try { let result = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); }
        catch(e) { alert(e); // error in the above string (in this case, yes)! 
        }
    } // if
} // onreadystatechange()
```